# .rpm does'nt install jdk package not even in terminal in kubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, rpm

[i tried installing jdk 10 through terminal ,as shown in picture,it gives error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7cZ8.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7cZ8.png
.rpm file is not installing package directly nor through terminal.

Answer (score -1):

There is probably a way but to my knowlage rpm packages are not made for ubuntu (might differ in Kbuntu) so you need to to convert it to deb (debain package) then install it.